# two 0 to 1 directions in a loop

Tags: c#, c++, function

This is so simple I can't believe I'm having so much trouble with it.

For an analogy to what I'm after imagine a two handed clock face, where instead of 12 hours the time was between 0 and 1.

The two hands can point in any direction, provided there values are 0 to 1, for example one pointing upwards and the other diagonally down and to the left would be 0 and 0.625.

I need a c++\c# function that given the position both hands and a bool representing if the larger or smaller segment between the hands is desired returns the position half way between both hands.

For example "0.2, 0.8, false" would refer to the smaller segment between both hands and the answer would be 0.

```
float func(float a, float b, bool side)
{
    return 0f;
}
```

In many cases the calculation would be simply "(a + b) * 0.5", however when crossing 0 as in the above example it is not. It's also not as simple as putting a single branch in like an "if". It seems there should be a solution far more elegant than ones I've tried.

edit: I've finally solved it myself, see the code below, additionally after various others attempted the peoblem a far more elegent solution was found.

```
float segment_size(float a, float b, bool side)
{
    float larger, smaller, c, d_smaller, d_larger;
    if (a > b)
    {
        smaller = b;
        larger = a;
    }
    else
    {
        smaller = a;
        larger = b;
    }
    c = larger - smaller;
    if (c > 0.5) {d_larger = c; d_smaller = 1 - c;} else {d_larger = 1 - c; d_smaller = c;}
    return side ? d_larger : d_smaller;
}

float func(float a, float b, bool side)
{
    float larger, smaller, c;
    if(a > b)
    {
        smaller = b;
        larger = a;
    }
    else
    {
        smaller = a;
        larger = b;
    }
    c = larger - smaller;
    float outf = 0, out1 = (float)((a + b) * 0.5),
    out3 = (float)(smaller - (segment_size(a, b, false) * 0.5)),
    out4 = (float)((smaller + larger) * 0.5);
    if(out4 > 0.5) {out4 -= 0.5f;} else {out4 += 0.5f;}
    if ((side == false && c <= 0.5) || (side == true && c > 0.5)) {outf = out1;}
    if (side == false && c > 0.5) {outf = out3;}
    if (side == true && c <= 0.5) {outf = out4;}
    if(outf < 0) {outf += 1;} if(outf >= 1) {outf -= 1;}
    return outf;
}
```

Comment: How should bool differentiate segments if they have the same size (for instance a=0, b=0.5)?

Comment: In this case then it dosn't matter either way.

Comment: Not a homework question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, so I got it very wrong the first time around (calculated the length of the segment instead of its halving point), and also the second time around (was kind of dodgy, so ended up deleting the answer), but bear with me.

The solution lies in the fact we're talking about a circle here. So if we have one halving point, we can get the other by adding half of the circumference of the circle (0.5) to that.

suppose 0<=a<1, 0<=b<1

```
if(a>b) {
   hi=a;
   lo=b;
} else {
   hi=b;
   lo=a;
}

d=hi-lo;

if( (d>0.5 && greater_segment_needed) || (d<=0.5 && !greater_segment_needed)) { 
    result=lo+d/2
} else
    result=lo+d/2+0.5; //the marvels of geometry
}

if(result>1) result-=1; //handling possible overflow
return result;
```

I'm pretty sure this works. And yeah, I edited it again >_>

Comment: Horray, you have succeeded where all others failed.

Answer (score 1):

You are right with (a+b)/2. But if result is greater then 0.5 it points out that its not the shorter part and you have to calculate over the zero to get it.

If you calculate over zero imagine that the greater number is negative. For example 0.8 is -0.2 (=a-1). And use the same equation you suggested. So 0.8 and 0.2 in your example would look like (-0.2 + 0.2)/2 = 0
Vice versa for size=true.

Source would look like tihs:

```
float func(float a, float b, bool side)
{
    float result = (a+b)/2;

    if (result > 0.5)
        result = (a+b-1)/2;

    if (side == true)
        return result;
    else
        return result<0.5 ? result+0.5 : result -0.5;
}
```

Comment: "0, 0.25, true" returns 0.875 instead of 0.625. Also both "0.8, 0.2, false" and "0.8, 0.2, true" return 0.5.

Comment: I had mistake in return ... it was wrong to subtract 1 to get opposite value in circle. Right is of course -0.5. This should be working well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my try. Not tested :)

```
float func(float a, float b, bool side)
{
  float seg_a = a - b;
  if (seg_a < 0) seg_a += 1;

  float seg_b = 1 - seg_a;
  float result;

  if (side && seg_a > 0.5 || !side && !(seg_a > 0.5))
    result = b + seg_a / 2;
  else
    result = a + seg_b / 2;

  if (result > 1) result -= 1;

  return result;
}
```

Comment: Not bad, much more robust than the first 2 attempts, very compact as well considering it almost works, unfortunatly "0.9, 0.2, false" returns a value greater than 1.

Comment: Oops, forgot about overflow. Fixed.

Comment: Iv'e been at this all day :¬P the odds are considerably against you. Compare notes with SáT and see if this works as well as his answer. I'm afraid I can only mark one as correct though.